# Migrate repos from github to github enterprise cloud without losing existing pull requests

Tags: git, github, github-enterprise

I want to migrate my existing repos from github to github enterprise cloud without losing the existing pull requests. I came across [ghe-migrator](https://github.blog/2016-05-16-migrate-your-repositories-using-ghe-migrator/) which is used to migrate repos from github to github enterprise server without losing the pull requests. Is there any other tool or support docs which will guide me to migrate the repos from github to github enterprise cloud ?

Comment: I found a way. This can be helpful for someone who is facing the similar situation [Github Enterprise importer](https://docs.github.com/en/early-access/github/migrating-with-github-enterprise-importer)